# StackOverflowError with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, stack-overflow

I'm getting a `StackOverflowError` when I try to merge with the `EntityManager`. Sorry that I only post the stacktrace and the entity I'm trying to persist, but I'm not very experienced with this, please comment about the code you may need to see.

In this link you will find the exception (too long for the post): http://jpst.it/vmGz. The repeating part is below:

```
...
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3887)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:458)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:427)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:260)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1078)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1005)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:651)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:471)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:666)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:828)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:707)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:940)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2111)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3887)
...
```

Here's the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaccional.auditoria")
public class Auditoria {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="transaccional.auditoria_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="transaccional.auditoria_id_seq", sequenceName="transaccional.auditoria_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="atencion_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private Atencion atencion;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="prescripcion_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private Prescripcion prescripcion;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="prestador_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private Prestador prestador;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tipo_transaccion_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private TipoTransaccion tipoTransaccion;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="nomenclador_practica_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private PracticaNomenclada nomencladorPractica;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="auditor_actual_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private Auditor auditorActual;

    @Column(name = "auditor_revision")
    private String auditorRevision;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="estado_auditoria_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private EstadoAuditoria estadoAuditoria;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "fecha_final")
    private Date fechaFinal;

    @Column(name = "cantidad_items")
    private Integer cantidadItems;

    @Column(name = "en_revision")
    private Boolean enRevision;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "fecha_comienzo_revision")
    private Date fechaComienzoRevision;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="ultimo_auditoria_detalle_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private AuditoriaDetalle ultimoAuditoriaDetalle;  

    @Column(name = "es_anulado")
    private Boolean esAnulado;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="fecha_insert")
    private Date fechaInsert;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="fecha_delete")
    private Date fechaDelete;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="fecha_update")
    private Date fechaUpdate;

    @Column(name="version")
    private int version;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="fecha_auditoria")
    private Date fechaAuditoria;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="motivo_auditoria_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private MotivoAuditoria motivoAuditoria;  

    @Column
    private String autorizacion;
    @Column
    private String origen;

    @Column(name="nro_autorizacion")
    private String nroAutorizacion;
```

Here is the service where it happens:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void update(Auditoria auditoria) {
    entityManager.merge(auditoria);
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you provide the part of the code where this error raises.

Comment: Have you overridden the equals method for your entity and if so, what does this method look like?

Comment: @JamesB I haven't overriden the equals method.

Comment: That link is broken.

Comment: @Tiny the link is working, if you are still having problems I'll change the host.

Comment: Looks like you overridden the equals method of some Entity as @JamesB stated. Add a breakpoint at the Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2111) or add debug logging messages at your application. There isn't much we can do. Basically Hibernate is iterating forever at your Entity graph because it thinks some `entity.equals(entity)` is returning false. Look for circular references within your mapping, that is a starting point.

Comment: @André thanks for your answer. I put the breakpoint where you said and I see the loop. What exactly I'm looking for here? Can I know this way which entity is causing me problems? I just identified the entity posted and one more which is not implementing ´equals´ as the first one.

Comment: You're looking for the offending entity. One that keeps getting loaded over and over.

Comment: @André the problem was that one of the entities had ´@AssociationOverrides´ annotations. I'm still not sure why this caused the problem. Any ideas?. By the way, post the comment that you mentioned the loader as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks.